# optimizer uses all the wrong indexes instead of one right

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, eav

This is another stupid question about optimizer. Synopsis is exactly as the subject is: the optimizer does it wrong. Seems like is has an absolute desire to use any index that contains *REALM_ID* field: I can create dozens of composite or simple indexes that contain this field, and as long as I add them into the `IGNORE INDEX` clause, it just picks another one. The thing is, this is actually a Keycloak with a custom app, so there's a layer of Hibernate framework abstraction, so instead of optimiser hints I'd rather change the whole query just in order to make optimizer just choose the primary key. I've also tried to add `order by UE.ID` clause to minify the influence of *REALM_ID*, but this doesn't help actually.

Table:

```
USER_ENTITY | CREATE TABLE `USER_ENTITY` (
  `ID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL_CONSTRAINT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL_VERIFIED` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `ENABLED` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `FEDERATION_LINK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `REALM_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_TIMESTAMP` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOT_BEFORE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_RU8TT6T700S9V50BU18WS5HA6` (`REALM_ID`,`USERNAME`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_DYKN684SL8UP1CRFEI6ECKHD7` (`REALM_ID`,`EMAIL_CONSTRAINT`),
  KEY `IDX_USER_EMAIL` (`EMAIL`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Query:

```
select UE.ID,
    UE.CREATED_TIMESTAMP,
    UE.EMAIL,
    UE.EMAIL_CONSTRAINT,
    UE.EMAIL_VERIFIED,
    UE.ENABLED,
    UE.FEDERATION_LINK,
    UE.FIRST_NAME,
    UE.LAST_NAME,
    UE.NOT_BEFORE,
    UE.REALM_ID,
    UE.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK,
    UE.USERNAME
from USER_ENTITY UE inner join USER_ATTRIBUTE AT on UE.ID=AT.USER_ID
where UE.REALM_ID='user' and
    AT.NAME='phone' and
    (NULL is null or UE.ID<>NULL) and
    AT.VALUE='01370003403';
```

Torture sequence:

***Untuned***:

```
MariaDB [sso]> select UE.ID, UE.CREATED_TIMESTAMP, UE.EMAIL, UE.EMAIL_CONSTRAINT, UE.EMAIL_VERIFIED, UE.ENABLED, UE.FEDERATION_LINK, UE.FIRST_NAME, UE.LAST_NAME, UE.NOT_BEFORE, UE.REALM_ID, UE.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK, UE.USERNAME from USER_ENTITY UE inner join USER_ATTRIBUTE AT on UE.ID=AT.USER_ID where UE.REALM_ID='user' and AT.NAME='phone' and (NULL is null or UE.ID<>NULL) and AT.VALUE='01370003403';
[..]
1 row in set (1.257 sec)
```

***Plan for untuned***:

```
MariaDB [sso]> explain select UE.ID, UE.CREATED_TIMESTAMP, UE.EMAIL, UE.EMAIL_CONSTRAINT, UE.EMAIL_VERIFIED, UE.ENABLED, UE.FEDERATION_LINK, UE.FIRST_NAME, UE.LAST_NAME, UE.NOT_BEFORE, UE.REALM_ID, UE.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK, UE.USERNAME from USER_ENTITY UE inner join USER_ATTRIBUTE AT on UE.ID=AT.USER_ID where UE.REALM_ID='user' and AT.NAME='phone' and (NULL is null or UE.ID<>NULL) and AT.VALUE='01370003403';
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                                       | key                                | key_len | ref                   | rows  | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | UE    | ref  | PRIMARY,UK_RU8TT6T700S9V50BU18WS5HA6,UK_DYKN684SL8UP1CRFEI6ECKHD7                   | UK_RU8TT6T700S9V50BU18WS5HA6       | 1023    | const                 | 90582 | Using index condition    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | AT    | ref  | IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE,IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_USER_VALUE,IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME_VALUE | IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME_VALUE | 1936    | sso.UE.ID,const,const | 1     | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

***Tuned***:

```
MariaDB [sso]> select UE.ID, UE.CREATED_TIMESTAMP, UE.EMAIL, UE.EMAIL_CONSTRAINT, UE.EMAIL_VERIFIED, UE.ENABLED, UE.FEDERATION_LINK, UE.FIRST_NAME, UE.LAST_NAME, UE.NOT_BEFORE, UE.REALM_ID, UE.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK, UE.USERNAME from USER_ENTITY UE IGNORE INDEX(UK_RU8TT6T700S9V50BU18WS5HA6, UK_DYKN684SL8UP1CRFEI6ECKHD7) inner join USER_ATTRIBUTE AT on UE.ID=AT.USER_ID where UE.REALM_ID='user' and AT.NAME='phone' and (NULL is null or UE.ID<>NULL) and AT.VALUE='01370003403';
    [...]
1 row in set (0.088 sec)
```

***Plan for tuned***:

```
MariaDB [sso]> explain select UE.ID, UE.CREATED_TIMESTAMP, UE.EMAIL, UE.EMAIL_CONSTRAINT, UE.EMAIL_VERIFIED, UE.ENABLED, UE.FEDERATION_LINK, UE.FIRST_NAME, UE.LAST_NAME, UE.NOT_BEFORE, UE.REALM_ID, UE.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK, UE.USERNAME from USER_ENTITY UE IGNORE INDEX(UK_RU8TT6T700S9V50BU18WS5HA6, UK_DYKN684SL8UP1CRFEI6ECKHD7) inner join USER_ATTRIBUTE AT on UE.ID=AT.USER_ID where UE.REALM_ID='user' and AT.NAME='phone' and (NULL is null or UE.ID<>NULL) and AT.VALUE='01370003403';
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+----------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                       | key                                | key_len | ref            | rows   | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+----------------+--------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | AT    | index  | IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE,IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_USER_VALUE,IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME_VALUE | IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME_VALUE | 1938    | NULL           | 178593 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | UE    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                             | PRIMARY                            | 146     | sso.AT.USER_ID | 1      | Using where              |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+----------------+--------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: I don't understand how mysql could use an index IDX_USER_ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME_VALUE on the at table, when tne user name is not given in the query.

Comment: It uses this index on another table, not on USER_ENTITY. And it's the USER entity "index scan" (so-called, tbecause it has 180R records, so its more like seqscan) that consumes most of the CPU time.

Comment: can you add the create table for the user_attribute table?

Comment: Do you know that " UE.ID<>NULL " is always false?

Comment: Yuup. But that nonsense is added by Hibernate, not me. :) I’ve just captured the bulk of lousy queries that appeared to be a bulk of one parametrized statement. :)

Comment: And actually no, its not always false. Au contraire, the whole part that you took this part from is always true. I mean the part in brackets. But again, this is Hibernate. Autostuff. Keycloak. You know.

Comment: Ah, the joys of hibernate are wasted on the DBA.  I preferred the movie (Hibernatus).

Comment: Have you executed analyze in both tables? Also, I believe it would help to create an index on AT.VALUE in case it has many distinct values (is it unique?)

Comment: An index on just `(realm_id, id)` would be better I think about this query. And an index on `(name, value, user_id)` on the user_attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

**EAV** schemas suck.  But this instance of it can be improved.

**The fix** (for the sluggishness)

```
ALTER TABLE USER_ATTRIBUTE
    ADD INDEX(NAME, VALUE, USER_ID);
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE  USER_ATTRIBUTE` -- there may be other improvements that can be made.

**Why** failed to use index(realm_id) ...

When looking up something by a secondary key, InnoDB first drills down the index's BTree to find a leaf row.  That leaf row contains the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then it has to drill down the data's BTree to find the desired row.  This 2-step process has some slowness.

The Optimizer says "if more than ~20% of the rows have `REALM_ID='user'`,  then don't bother with the secondary index; simply scan the table".

A `JOIN` is almost always performed by NLJ (Nested Loop Join), meaning that it gets the desired rows from one table.  As it gets a row, it reaches into the next table.

My suggested index to the *other* table will encourage the Optimizer to *start* with the attribute table.  This will *probably* finish much faster.

Comment: I believe an index on `(realm_id, id)` on the entity table would also be used and improve performance. Or just `(realm_id)` which would be essentially the same since (id) is the primary key and table is innodb.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Yes.  In InnoDB, they are the same.  In some situations (maybe not this one), I tack on ",id" to remind the programmer (me) that I am depending on it being part of the index.